# How to keep Bottom Navigation View after opening an Activity from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I'm a beguinner with Android programming, and in my app I have a Bottom Navigation View with 3 fragments.
One of those fragments has a button that allows the user to open another Activity to listen to music. But whenever the Activity is opened using Intents, the Bottom Navigation View from the previous screens disappears.

Can I open an Activity from a Fragment, but still have the Bottom Navigation View active?

Below is attached a link with an image of the mock-up I've made, hope it helps to clarify the question:

[image: Link to the mock-up example]

Thank you in advance for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

Well I guess (because I have no clue about your code base) the bottom navigation bar is a part of the main activity in which the fragments are being contained. When you are starting a new activity, the main activity with the bottom navigation goes as the music player layout loads.

---

### Recommended Solution

Instead of keeping the music player as an activity **make it a fragment** and load in the view you are using as the fragment container in the main activity.

---

### Another Way round *(Not recommended)*

Make another view of the bottom navigation bar in the music player activity and map the actions of the button click to load the main activity.
It might be a bit time taking and buggy initially but with debugging and testing, you can make it work.
But again its not a good option.